# how to change primary color of gnome-shel 3.12?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, gnome-shell

I want to change main color of gnome-shell 3.12 that use in any where that doesn't specify background-color in gnome-shell.css stylesheet.
I want to change all menu background-color.

I try these:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'none'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#3C78B4'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#1E3C5A'
```

with sudo and without it and search lot of in google but no result!

Comment: why you get negative vote to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tool `elegance-colors`. You can install it with:
`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-theme-elegance-colors`

Then open the GUI tool `Elegance Colors` from your applications list or type `elegance-colors-prefs` in the terminal to open it. In the left sidebar you'll find everything you need to customize your theme or load themes from presets.